# Canvas and text don't match

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Firstly, my scene got deleted in Unity and i'm doing everything again. I've created this canvas

[image]

and put it so it matches with the camera. Then, I want to create a text but for some reason the size does not match the canvas.

[image]

I've tried changing the render mode, distance... but it does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at the canvas scaler - is that the native resolution you're developing in? If not change it. Also play around with the canvas scaler controls, e.g. width vs height etc - it can have some surprising results but do the use resolution preview in the editor.
If that doesn't help the simple answer would seem to be to change the font size in the TextMesh component. Write back or edit the question if you have more input.